# How to make a layou or image is over the Toolbar and TabLayout

Tags: android

I'm racking my brain here how to make a layout is above the Toolbar and TabLayout as the image:

[layout is above the Toolbar and TabLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ4mx.png)

I've tried with onCreateOptionsMenu but did not succeed: / if someone can me a hint of how to do this, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) is one way of achieving this.

Just create a popup window and supply it the content view.  This is the view defining your popup content.

```
setContentView(View contentView)
```

Then simply place it using an `anchorView` which in your case would be the trophy image.

You can use `showAsDropDown (View anchor)` or any of the other show methods depending on where you need to place it exactly.

Comment: Hello Thank you helped me, but how to open displayPopupWindow in onCreate

Comment: You will have to let the onCreate finish.  So use view.post(new Runnable(//your showing code in here)); where view could be any view from your activity.  This will let onCreate() finish and then invoke show